# Installling a laptop optical drive in a desktop

Tags: optical-drive, case

For no reason other then awesome factor, I want to install a slot-loading optical drive in my new computer.

Now, a lot of searching has proved that slot-loading optical drives don't come in 5.25 inch form factor; they're only for laptops.

So, how would you go about mounting a laptop-size optical drive into a 5.25 inch bay?

My ideas involve making some custom brackets, and then modifying the blanking plug in the case to allow for the different size of the drive. This is a last resort, however, as I would much rather use an off the shelf product if one exists.

[This](http://3btech.net/bydrbaytrbrm.html) looks ideal, but it's only available in the United States, which is no good for me. I live in the UK, so it would need to be available from an EU supplier.

Any solutions, no matter how crazy, are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the (UK) companies that specialise in small form factor systems do slim drive mounting brackets - for example:

**Slim CD/DVD + 3.5" HDD Drive Bay - 5.25"**

*This Bezel Kit solution allows a slimline optical drive and a 3.5" HDD to be installed in 5.25” optical drive bays found on desktops and servers.
Slimline form factor optical drives – CD-ROM, DVD, and Blu-Ray included – are usually designed for laptop and portable computer systems. Because of their form factor, other desktop and server-type users are likely to find useful applications for slim drives in their systems. This unique bezel solution allows you to use a single slim optical drive for 5.25” drive bays.*

http://linitx.com/product/12680

See also:

**Dual Slim CD Drive Bay - 5.25"**

*Custom DUAL slim-line bezel, which allows for two CD/DVD drives to sit in the form factor of one 5.25" bay.*

http://linitx.com/product/11216

Comment: That is pretty much exactly what I was looking for, thankyou very much.

Answer (score 0):

As you've mentioned that you live in the UK, [Maplins](http://www.maplin.co.uk/hard-disk-drive-fixing-kit-with-anti-vibration-98837) sell a 3.5" >< 5.25in bracket set, basically two pieces of "U" shaped metal than can be used to fix a hard disk in the space of a CD/DVD drive slot. I would think that this would work, although I have never mounted a laptop "slimline" drive outside of a laptop, so see if this would be OK.

Answer (score 0):

I have engineered my own wire frame to load up 3 "laptop" optical drives into one 5.25" bay how ever it needs two things
[1] A neat little bezel to cover the two opening left exposed
[2] adapters to convert the interface from slim to standard PATA

I tried the SATA and they worked like a charm so now I'm gonna get my craftsman to make the bezel. The only problem I have now is 3 slim PATA 8x DVD Writers sitting on a shelf with nothing to do :( so I am back to square 1 I still got 3 perfectly working drives sitting on a shelf:(

Answer (score 0):

got your answer right here bud I have been searching for the same thing now now found it I stay in uk as well is on amazon uk thank you for pointing me in right direction

http://www.amazon.co.uk/Lian-Li-Optical-Drive-EX-553/dp/B003LLRV48/ref=sr_1_28?s=computers&ie=UTF8&qid=1421887936&sr=1-28&keywords=optical+Drive+2.5+-+5.25

Comment: Can you explain what this product is and how it addresses the OP's problem?